# Compute fourier transform of huge list of functions faster

Tags: performance-tuning, fourier-analysis

I want to compute the Fourier transform in the form of trigonometric functions from a list of functions. Suppose I have `F1` like below:

```
F1 = 
  Table[
    Sum[(jj - m) y^(2 (jj - 2 - i) + 4) x^(2 m + 2 i + 4), {i, 1,jj - 3}] + 
    Sum[ y^(2 (i) + 4) x^(2 m + 2 (jj - 2 - i) + 2) + (m*jj) x^(2 m) y^(2 (jj - 1) + 6), {i, jj - 3, jj - 2}], 
    {m,50}, {jj, 4, 50}]
```

I get the Laplacian from this list of functions:

```
F2 = Laplacian[F1, {x, y}]
```

Then I get the Fourier transform from F2:

```
a = 1
ParallelTable[
  1/a Integrate[Cos[(n π y)/a]*F2[[m, jj]] /. {x -> 4} , {y, -a, a}], 
  {n, 30}, {m, 50}, {jj, 4, 50}]
```

Please help me with doing this computation as fast as possible? I need 10 precision accuracy.

Comment: Use [FourierCosCoefficient](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierCosCoefficient.html)

Comment: but it's domain differs from my domain

Comment: I think the index `jj` in your `ParallelTable` should be `{jj, 47}` -- `jj` is an index here, rather than a variable, and `F2` only has 47 columns.

Comment: I want to  get list of function with dimensions at least 47*50 and it's answer some equations that requires jj start from 4 to end for 1 to 3 we have different answer which shape of function differ from the form I presented. what's important here for me making the third row of code as fast as possible and desired accuracy

Answer (score 3):

To speed it up, regard your F2 terms, They are all polynoms of y

```
F2[[3, 3]] /. x -> 4

(*   386547056640 y^4 + 238370684928 y^6 + 13784580096 y^8 + 
     429785088 y^10 + 229376 y^12 + 35389440 y^14 + 276480 y^16     *)
```

Therfore you can get a general epression for the fourier integral

```
int = Integrate[1/a*Cos[(n \[Pi] y)/a]*y^k, {y, -a, a}, 
        Assumptions -> 
            k > 1 && k \[Element] Integers && n \[Element] Integers && n > 0 &&
 a > 0]

(*     (1/(1 + k))((-a)^k + a^k) HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 + k/2}, {1/2, 
          3/2 + k/2}, -(1/4) n^2 \[Pi]^2]     *)
```

Insert this instead of the integral.

```
(a = 1;
 partab2 = 
    ParallelTable[
     F2[[m, jj]] /. {x -> 4, y^k_ -> int} // N, {n, 30}, {m, 1, 
       3}, {jj, 1, 3}];) // AbsoluteTiming

(*     {3.6250272, Null}     *)
```

Compare the calculation times with "Integrate" and "NIntegrate" for a small parameter set.

```
(a = 1;
  partab = 
    ParallelTable[
       1/a Integrate[
        Cos[(n \[Pi] y)/a]*F2[[m, jj]] /. {x -> 4}, {y, -a, a}] // 
        N, {n, 30}, {m, 1, 3}, {jj, 1, 3}];) // AbsoluteTiming

(*     {103.0479747, Null}     *)

(a = 1;
  partabn = 
    ParallelTable[
     1/a NIntegrate[
      Cos[(n \[Pi] y)/a]*F2[[m, jj]] /. {x -> 4}, {y, -a, a}], {n, 
      30}, {m, 1, 3}, {jj, 1, 3}];) // AbsoluteTiming

(*     {6.6719206, Null}     *)
```

Comment: You are right. I correct it just now. Doesn't change much.